# Dart: How do I improve code reuse in two different subclass if there are two same function in them but only the return types are different?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

I have two different class, which are both the subclass of another base class, and a method in each to return an object, doing same things but returning different type, is it possible to write this method in the base class?

```
class base {}

class subclassOne extends base {
  subclassOne doSomething() {
    //doing some common things
    return subclassOne();
  }
}

class subclassTwo extends base {
  subclassTwo doSomething() {
    //doing some common things
    return subclassTwo();
  }
}
```

I have tried this, but apparently the compiler said this.runtimeType is not a type.

```
class base {
  base doSomething() {
    //doing some common things
    return base() as this.runtimeType;
  }
}

class subclassOne extends base {}

class subclassTwo extends base {}
```

Comment: Use Static keyword and write static function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward approach would be to just refactor your code so that the common work is shared:

```dart
abstract class Base {
  void doCommonThings() {
    // Do some common things.
  }

  Base doSomething();
}

class SubclassOne extends Base {
  @override
  SubclassOne doSomething() {
    doCommonThings();
    return SubclassOne();
  }
}

class SubclassTwo extends Base {
  @override
  SubclassTwo doSomething() {
    doCommonThings();
    return SubclassTwo();
  }
}
```

A variation of that would be to add a method that returns a new subclass instance from an existing instance. (The code below makes `Base` generic so that `doSomething` is statically known to return the subclass type.)

```dart
abstract class Base<T extends Base<T>> {
  T doSomething() {
    // Do some common things.
    return copyWith();
  }

  T copyWith();
}

class SubclassOne extends Base<SubclassOne> {
  @override
  SubclassOne copyWith() => SubclassOne();
}

class SubclassTwo extends Base<SubclassTwo> {
  @override
  SubclassTwo copyWith() => SubclassTwo();
}
```

A more general version of that would be for the subclasses to provide a callback instead of a method override:

```dart
abstract class Base {
  T doCommonThings<T extends Base>(T Function() makeInstance) {
    // Do some common things.
    return makeInstance();
  }

  Base doSomething();
}

class SubclassOne extends Base {
  @override
  SubclassOne doSomething() => doCommonThings(SubclassOne.new);
}

class SubclassTwo extends Base {
  @override
  SubclassTwo doSomething() => doCommonThings(SubclassTwo.new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using generics `<T>`

```dart
class Base<T> {
  T doSomething() {
    //doing some common things
    return this as T;
  }
}

class SubclassOne extends Base<SubclassOne> {}

class SubclassTwo extends Base<SubclassTwo> {}
```

Comment: OP wants `doSomething()` to return a new instance, not to return `this`. (`return this` is usually unnecessary in Dart anyway.)